# Google Cloud SQL [PostgreSQL] Database storage is Increasing

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, gcp

I have a database instance (PostgreSQL v12.6) on Google Cloud and since 10 days ago, the Storage of Database is increasing rapidly.

Here's my Observations:

[list of Dtabases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92qKn.png)

[Dashboard of Disk Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52qpc.png)

From the second image, the data[App data] & archived_wal_log data is increasing enormously from the last 10 days

we have enabled the Automated backups & Point-in-time recovery & also enabled the Autoscaling of storage. So it increases the storage whenever the size of Database increases.

Can anybody help on this, why Archived_wal_log is increasing the data

Thanks

Sriram

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You [may consider reading this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013896/google-cloud-sql-postgresql-storage-keeps-growing). They point to Point in time recovery. If you don't need this consider disabling it.

Comment: @vidarlo - Just checked my backup settings, the PITR is enabled. If i disabled the PITR then the storage space will shrink. So is there any data loss will happen. 
Did you check my first  image i.e.; list of databases. From the past few days our team uploaded a lot of data and the mirth-connect database size increases. Then archived_wal-log size also increases. How PITR & archived_wal_log are interlinked. can you explain

Comment: Do you understand what `point-in-time recovery` and `write-ahead-logging` do and how they are implemented? You do not have a problem. You enabled features that require additional disk space (e.g. a lot more disk space).

Comment: @JohnHanley - I understood what's does PITR & WAL but my concern is one database is growing the size day by day and also parallelly Archived WAL size is increasing the double the Original size. I checked the size of tables in that database and it's in normal size. If i disabled the PITR then it automatically decrease the Storage Space.